# My SQL Ajax table keeps repeating ID's, Usernames, etc on the table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm building a database table for class where I must present data from MySQL database into the table.

The issue i'm having is that after 100 ID's, the usernames and everything repeat. Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBkij.jpg

I'm a huge coding noob and trying everything and can't seem to fix it

---

Here's my code

```
<?php

//connection to DB
require "connectionPages/remoteConnect.php";

$userSQL = "SELECT * FROM USER, CUSTOMER";          

$result = $mysqli->query($userSQL);

$pTable =   "<div class='table'>
        <div class='heading'>
            <div class='cell'></div>
            <div class='cell'>ID</div>
            <div class='cell'>userName</div>
            <div class='cell'>custEmail</div>
            <div class='cell'>Last Name</div>
        </div>";

while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
    $ID             = $row['userID'];
    $userName   = $row['userName'];
    $custEmail  = $row['custEmail'];
    $userLname  = $row['custLName'];

    $pTable .=  "<div class='row'>
                    <div class='cell'>
                        <a class='delete'>Delete</a>
                        <a class='edit'>Edit</a>
                        <a class='cancel'>Cancel</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class='cell'><input disabled size='2' type='text' name='txtID' value='$ID'></div>
                    <div class='cell'><input disabled size='25' type='text' name='txtFirst' value='$userName'></div>
                    <div class='cell'><input disabled size='25' type='text' name='txtEmail' value='$custEmail'></div>
                    <div class='cell'><input disabled size='25' type='text' name='txtTeam' value='$userLname'></div>
                </div>";
}

//close out table tag
$pTable .= "</div><p><a href='outputPages/enterUser.php'>Add A User</a></p>";

//close connection to DB
$mysqli->close();

$doc = "<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>
                <script src='clientCode/jquery-1.12.2.min.js'></script>
                <script src='clientCode/AJAX.js'></script>
                <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/tableStyle.css'>
                </head>
            <body>
                $pTable
            </body>
        </html>";

echo $doc;

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your SQL query: `SELECT * FROM USER, CUSTOMER`;
that selects all rows from USER for each row in CUSTOMER!
Pretty sure that is not what you want.

If you tell us the columns in each of those tables, we can probably help you further. You probably want to (LEFT?) JOIN both tables (a guess).

*edit: Per your DB schema, your query should be:

`SELECT * FROM USER, CUSTOMER WHERE USER.custID = CUSTOMER.custID`

This will give you one row per customer.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response

For USER I need: userName and userID

For CUSTOMER I need: custEmail, and custLName 

I may add more later, but as long as i'm back on track hopefully I won't need help afterward. 

I hope that is the info you requested

Comment: @JonR What is the column in CUSTOMER that references the associated row in USER? (Might also be a column in USER that references a row in CUSTOMER.)

Comment: I am slightly confused, but maybe this can help you http://imgur.com/a/2c134   again thank you for the time

Comment: I should also mention that the database itself is called ctollins_TRTdesign

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you Guillaume for the help, I'm forever greatful

Answer (score 0):

You should specyfy shered column between those tables eg.

```
$userSQL = "SELECT * FROM USER, CUSTOMER WHERE USER.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER.ID";
```

Or better use JOIN statment

```
    $userSQL = "SELECT * FROM USER u JOIN CUSTOMER c ON u.CUSTOMER_ID = c.ID";
```